# Keeping Bullets on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have radio buttons of the same group but cannot figure out how to force them to all be on the same line. Does anyone have any CSS tricks for keeping them all on the same line instead of dropping the last bullet to the next line?

[image]

```
<div id="ownership">
        <label class='radiolabel'>
    <input type="radio" name="ownership" required="yes" value="BOAT MCO" />Manufacturer's Statement of Origin</label>
    <label class='radiolabel'>
    <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="BOAT FL Title" />Florida Certificate of Title</label>
    <label class='radiolabel'>
    <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="BOAT OOS Title" />Out-of-state Certificate of Title</label>
    <label class='radiolabel'>
    <input type="radio" name="ownership" value="TN Required" />I do not have any of these</label>

</div>

#ownership input[type=radio]{
    margin:3px;
    margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean "keep them on the same line"?

Comment: does the parent have a fixed width? If so, it probably just doesn't fit.

Comment: It seems to be related to your CSS, could you provide it

Comment: basically the bullet "I do not have any of these" needs to come back up

Comment: @ZaneZ you can force that with `white-space: nowrap;` but then it will overflow the parent div which is set to a fixed width.

Comment: what do u mean it will overflow?

Comment: @ZaneZ I mean the content will become larger than the parent div.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Since they are considered inline elements, you should be able to use `white-space: nowrap;` on the parent. Like so:

```
#ownership {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I will accept this answer in 10 min when it lets me

Comment: Glad it helped. :) As other people have pointed out, though, it may have strange consequences for your design. All that text will stay on the same line even if it gets too long to fit. This means it may continue past the right edge of its container/the page if you aren't careful.

Answer (score 1):

There is no general reason why they should *not* be on a single line. all elements you use are inline elements, so they follow the flow of your page. Two reasons might exist why that is *not* the case for you:

1. there is not enough room in the containing element, thus the line has to be wrapped just like with every other text
2. you have style rules that change the default behavior.

The screenshot you posted suggests that 1. is the case here. So you have to take care to either widen your containing element or, if that is auto sized, to prevent a line break in the line of radio buttons. Have a try using `white-space: nowrap;` in that case.

Answer (score 0):

Try display:inline-block and a width in % https://jsfiddle.net/ow7Lsz7z/

```
label{
    display:inline-block;
    width:22%;
    margin-left:2%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to write your code between `<frame>` Your bullets `</frame>`

Comment: Please expand on this to turn it into a full-fledged answer! Thanks!